# When should we use containerized application on Linux

Tags: linux, performance, docker, lxc, containers

I would like to create a Linux server but I'm stuck on one question:

- How to know when I should use Docker or Lxc for a given application instead of installing it natively ?

For example, on my server (maybe CentOS minimal or Arch Linux or Alpine Linux depending on the answers to this question), I would like to install:

- Python 3
- FTP server
- Mono
- PHP
- NGiNX
- Docker (or Lxc)
- many others app

What about the performances:

- Will my server be faster with or without containers ?
- Will it be more secure (CVE vulnerabilities)
- Will it be easier to maintain (software updates) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bare metal (what I think you mean by *natively*) is usually more performant than any kind of virtualization/containerization simply due to the fact that there is less system overhead between hardware, kernel and OS.

A container is going to give you the benefit of managing multiple instances of an OS (snapshots, migration, image dumps/backups, resource prioritization, etc.) without incurring a heavy performance penalty. Containerization security does have some disadvantages over full virtualization however.

A full VM would be a better choice when performance is less of a concern since fully virtualization usually involves emulating various hardware devices. Each virtual instance is a complete operating system (with exception of hardware pass-through) processes, kernel, libraries and applications running within it. It's considered to be much harder for an attacker to break out of a fully virtualized host over a container but this risk/attack surface is going to vary by vendor.

If you're not doing extremely heavy I/O or CPU utilization, you probably won't see a big performance hit for either containers or full VMs. As an example, containerization would be a better choice for something like a software testing or compilation node where you want the best performance you can get to lessen development lead times, however you still want to be able to snapshot or roll-back installations easily (something you cannot do easily with bare-metal).

You will probably have to experiment with you software stack a bit but with the list you've give, I would go full virtualization to get all the benefits of security and VM management.

Comment: Your answer seems to be the right on, regarding my needs and I'll keep using bare-metal instead of trying to container because I'll use a physical server and I can't waste resources with virtualization.